# Properly formatting CSV with hstore data for Postgres import

Tags: postgresql, csv, hstore

I have a Postgres table that looks like this.

```
       Column    |       Type        |       Modifiers        
   --------------+-------------------+------------------------
    id           | bigint            | not null
    tags         | hstore            | not null
```

I want to import data from a CSV file into this table. As a first test, I imported this single line CSV

```
1234,""key"=>"value""
```

using

```
COPY my_table FROM 'my_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

which worked fine.

**However**, in the hstore data I want to import, the keys and values can be any string under the sun, possibly containing quotes or any other exotic characters. How should I format my CSV file to allow imports of hstore columns where the key-value pairs contain arbitrary strings?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using Postgres 9.5.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some "rare" characters as delimiter, like

`COPY my_table FROM 'my_file.csv' DELIMITER E'\x02' CSV;`

Do you expect ASCII `chr(2)` in your values?..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I would prefer to not make any assumptions about the input data, hence _"arbitrary strings"_.

Comment: ah. I thought it would be one time import, so you can check if you have any chr(2) before it...